# Adding an image form element to an add/edit form

Tags: magento2, image, uicomponent, crud

I'm building a CRUD module for Magento 2 using ui components for admin list and form and one of my entities has an image field.
But I cannot make it work as it should.
Here is how it should work.
When in add mode or in edit mode with no uploaded image it should look like a simple file input.

[image]

When a file is uploaded it should show the image preview and a delete box below it.

[image]

I'm not looking for the exactly this design. It could look differently but have the same functionality.

In Magento 1 I was able to do this, just by creating my own block renderer

```
class {{Namespace}}_{{Module}}_Block_Adminhtml_{{Entity}}_Helper_Image extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Image
{
    protected function _getUrl()
    {
        $url = false;
        if ($this->getValue()) {
            $url = Mage::helper('{{namespace}}_{{module}}/{{entity}}_image')->getImageBaseUrl().$this->getValue();
        }
        return $url;
    }
}
```

And adding this in my form block

```
    $fieldset->addType(
        'image',
        Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('{{namespace}}_{{module}}/adminhtml_{{entity}}_helper_image')
    );
```

But I have no form block in Magento 2.
I know I can use a class name for a form field in the ui components file

```
    <field name="image" class="Class\Name\Here">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Resume</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">image</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">[entity]</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">image</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

Obviously I have to create this class, but what should I extend?
All I know is that I need to implement the interface `Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentInterface` but I found nothing I can extend.
So my real question is: **Can I extend some class to achieve the desired behavior? If not, how can I start creating this element renderer?**

Comment: Hi @Marius , I tried to use your example to be able to add product images in my custom grid edit page, but got this error : Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Data_Form_Element_' not found in ...\lib\Varien\Data\Form\Abstract.php on line 146

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found a way to do it without requiring a class attached to the field. I mean there is a class attached to the form element but not as a renderer.
The column should be defined as this:

```
<field name="image">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">[entity]</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
            <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">[Namespace]_[Module]/image-preview</item>
            <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="[namespace_module]/[entity]_image/upload"/>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

I also needed to create the preview template file referenced by `[Namespace]_[Module]/image-preview`.
That is `app/code/[Namespace]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/web/template/image-preview.html` that looks like this:

```
<div class="file-uploader-summary">
    <div class="file-uploader-preview">
        <a attr="href: $parent.getFilePreview($file)" target="_blank">
            <img
                class="preview-image"
                tabindex="0"
                event="load: $parent.onPreviewLoad.bind($parent)"
                attr="
                    src: $parent.getFilePreview($file),
                    alt: $file.name">
        </a>

        <div class="actions">
            <button
                type="button"
                class="action-remove"
                data-role="delete-button"
                attr="title: $t('Delete image')"
                click="$parent.removeFile.bind($parent, $file)">
                <span translate="'Delete image'"/>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="file-uploader-filename" text="$file.name"/>
    <div class="file-uploader-meta">
        <text args="$file.previewWidth"/>x<text args="$file.previewHeight"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code will generate a field like this:

[image]

After uploading an image (real time) it looks like this:

[image]

The `url`  item inside the `uploaderConfig` is the url where the image is posted when uploaded. So I needed to create this also:

```
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Controller\Adminhtml\[Entity]\Image;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

/**
 * Class Upload
 */
class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * Image uploader
     *
     * @var \[Namespace]\[Module]\Model\ImageUploader
     */
    protected $imageUploader;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \[Namespace]\[Module]\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \[Namespace]\[Module]\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
    }

    /**
     * Check admin permissions for this controller
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('[Namespace]_[Module]::[entity]');
    }

    /**
     * Upload file controller action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('image');

            $result['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
    }
}
```

This class uses an instance of `[Namespace]\[Module]\Model\ImageUploader` that is similar to `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader`.

This seams to work. I still have troubles saving the image in the db but that's a totally different issue.
I used as inspiration the `image` field for the category entity

Comment: I can successfully upload image and save image name into database, then when I open record i just created, all fields other than image field are all showing as expected. When I change the image field to just a normal "text" field, then it will show. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: @Nero. You need the image value in a certain json format. [Here is an example](https://github.com/tzyganu/Magento2SampleModule/blob/master/Ui/DataProvider/Author/Form/Modifier/AuthorData.php#L54) on how you can transform it to the proper json

Comment: I don't want to upload image but i want to display image in admin Ui form.Actually i upload image from frontend form and want to display it in admin ui form.So please help me how to do

Comment: There is error in [Namespace]\[Module]\Controller\Adminhtml\[Entity]\Image\upload.php on line number 61 Please check and update answer.

Comment: @PrincePatel What's the error message?

Comment: syntax error, unexpected ','  on line 61

Comment: Now it's show unexpected ')' error. You need to update with $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];

Comment: @Marius looks great, but if the form is in Edit mode, how can i make the file uploader field and thumbnail template to read from the dataprovider in the getData function/

Comment: @Marius found answer to that here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138642/magento-2-1-image-not-uploading-in-edit-form

Comment: @Marius I see below error in my console when I try to upload an image
please check: 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Forbidden)

Comment: is it 404 or forbidden? anyway, check if the controller exists or if you have write access for the uploads

Comment: hello @Marius in construct you have been using the \[Namespace]\[Module]\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader then i should define in di.xml and should have imageuploader in model file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the class you should extend is `\Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\AbstractElement`.

This class implements the `ElementInterface` which itself extends the `UiComponentInterface` you're referring to.

On top of that, if you check the components declared under `Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element` you can see that they all extend that class.

<del>The reason I would choose this class is because the `render` method of `\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Element` only accepts such class type:</del> (This is actually an instance of `Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement` that is accepted, not `\Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\AbstractElement` )

Comment: Any pointers on how my class should look like?

Comment: @Marius hmmm I'm not too sure, I'll try to find out

Comment: I don't think you need to do that yet. I think I found a solution without using a class in the ui component, but I need to test first.

Comment: @Marius hmmmm I think I was wrong, I reckon you should check that out: https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-form-uicomponent