# Magento 2.1 image not uploading in edit form

Tags: magento-2.1, forms, image-upload

I am working on **magento 2.1** form. Image is uploaded successfully when i add new field. however when i edit any field from grid then file **uploader** will not shown on page.
When i inspect edit page it shows following error

> Uncaught TypeError: value.map is not a function  in
>   file-uploader.js:69

```
<field name="image">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">faqs</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Topic Image</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item> 
               <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item> 
               <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">image</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">13</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="faqs/topic_image/upload"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

In \app\code\Spacename\Moduelname\etc\di.xml

```
<type name="Spacename\modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Topic\Image\Upload">
<arguments>
    <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUpload</argument>
</arguments>
</type>


<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUpload" type="spacename\modulename\Model\ImageUploader">
<arguments>
    <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">faqs</argument>
    <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">faqs</argument>
    <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
        <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
        <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
        <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
    </argument>
</arguments>
```

In controller app\code\Spacename\Moduelname\Controller\Adminhtml\Topic\Image    upload.php

```
    class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * Image uploader
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader
     */
    protected $baseTmpPath;
    protected $imageUploader;

    /**
     * Upload constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \spacename\modulename\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
    }

    /**
     * Check admin permissions for this controller
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('spacename_Modulename::entity');
    }

    /**
     * Upload file controller action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {

        try {
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('image');

            $result['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
    }
}
```

and in model \code\Spacename\Moduelname\Model\ImageUploader.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace spacename\modulename\Model;

/**
 * Catalog image uploader
 */
class ImageUploader
{
    /**
     * Core file storage database
     *
     * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database
     */
    protected $coreFileStorageDatabase;

    /**
     * Media directory object (writable).
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface
     */
    protected $mediaDirectory;

    /**
     * Uploader factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory
     */
    private $uploaderFactory;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * Base tmp path
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $baseTmpPath;

    /**
     * Base path
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $basePath;

    /**
     * Allowed extensions
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $allowedExtensions;

    /**
     * ImageUploader constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDatabase
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param string $baseTmpPath
     * @param string $basePath
     * @param string[] $allowedExtensions
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDatabase,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        $baseTmpPath,
        $basePath,
        $allowedExtensions
    ) {
        $this->coreFileStorageDatabase = $coreFileStorageDatabase;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->baseTmpPath = $baseTmpPath;
        $this->basePath = $basePath;
        $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;
    }

    /**
     * Set base tmp path
     *
     * @param string $baseTmpPath
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setBaseTmpPath($baseTmpPath)
    {
        $this->baseTmpPath = $baseTmpPath;
    }

    /**
     * Set base path
     *
     * @param string $basePath
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setBasePath($basePath)
    {
        $this->basePath = $basePath;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowed extensions
     *
     * @param string[] $allowedExtensions
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAllowedExtensions($allowedExtensions)
    {
        $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve base tmp path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBaseTmpPath()
    {

        return $this->baseTmpPath;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve base path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBasePath()
    {
        return $this->basePath;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve base path
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getAllowedExtensions()
    {
        return $this->allowedExtensions;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve path
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param string $imageName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFilePath($path, $imageName)
    {
        return rtrim($path, '/') . '/' . ltrim($imageName, '/');
    }

    /**
     * Checking file for moving and move it
     *
     * @param string $imageName
     *
     * @return string
     *
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function moveFileFromTmp($imageName)
    {
        $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();
        $basePath = $this->getBasePath();


        $baseImagePath = $this->getFilePath($basePath, $imageName);
        $baseTmpImagePath = $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $imageName);

        try {
            $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->copyFile(
                $baseTmpImagePath,
                $baseImagePath
            );
            $this->mediaDirectory->renameFile(
                $baseTmpImagePath,
                $baseImagePath
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('Something went wrong while saving the file(s).')
            );
        }

        return $imageName;
    }

    /**
     * Checking file for save and save it to tmp dir
     *
     * @param string $fileId
     *
     * @return string[]
     *
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function saveFileToTmpDir($fileId)
    {
        $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();

        $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $fileId]);
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions($this->getAllowedExtensions());
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);

        $result = $uploader->save($this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($baseTmpPath));

        if (!$result) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('File can not be saved to the destination folder.')
            );
        }

        /**
         * Workaround for prototype 1.7 methods "isJSON", "evalJSON" on Windows OS
         */
        $result['tmp_name'] = str_replace('\\', '/', $result['tmp_name']);
        $result['path'] = str_replace('\\', '/', $result['path']);
        $result['url'] = $this->storeManager
                ->getStore()
                ->getBaseUrl(
                    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
                ) . $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $result['file']);
        $result['name'] = $result['file'];

        if (isset($result['file'])) {
            try {
                $relativePath = rtrim($baseTmpPath, '/') . '/' . ltrim($result['file'], '/');
                $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->saveFile($relativePath);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e);
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __('Something went wrong while saving the file(s).')
                );
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why not using the original Magento file uploader ?

Comment: i am following magneto catalog uploader .any other solution please discuss

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you have to pass pass image array that contain image `url,name`

for passing it to ui component you can use **dataprovider**

```
<argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Modulen\Model\Modelname\DataProvider</argument>
```

pass array like below.

```
           $categoryData['image'][0]['name'] = $category->getData('image');
           $categoryData['image'][0]['url'] = $category->getImageUrl();
```

for the reference you can look

**vendor\magento\Magento_Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider.php**

[Complete example](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-ui-component-image-upload/)

Comment: This is working fine for single image, but If i have added small,medium, large,extralarge images means, How Do i change the dataprovider.php

Comment: @Sri   You can add multiple image from DataProvider. 
`$categoryData['image'][0]['name'] = $category->getData('image');
           $categoryData['image'][0]['url'] = $category->getImageUrl();
$categoryData['samllimage'][0]['name'] = $category->getData('smallimage');
           $categoryData['smallimage'][0]['url'] = $category->getImageUrl();`

Answer (score 8):

As stated by Qaisar, the idea is to use the data provider to add those information to the data.

So in your form ui_component you first need to specify a data source:

```
<dataSource name="faqs_form_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Spacename\Modulename\Model\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">faqs_form_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="faqs/topic_image/save"/>
                <item name="validate_url" xsi:type="url" path="faqs/topic_image/validate"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
```

So that's as an example you may have to adapt this code to your needs.

On top of that still in your ui component xml file you need to specify the data source in the data argument node by adding:

```
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">faqs_form.faqs_form_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">faqs_form.faqs_form_data_source</item>
    </item>
```

Then you need to create the data provider `Spacename\Modulename\Model\DataProvider`.

This is hard to give you a sample of that file as that will depend on your need but the critical part is to add the image URL and name to your data.

To do so, you need to update the `getData` method:

```
public function getData()
{
    if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
    $faq = $this->getCurrentFaq();
    if ($faq) {
        $faqData = $faq->getData();
        if (isset($faqData['image'])) {
            unset($faqData['image']);
            $faqData['image'][0]['name'] = $faqData->getData('image');
            $faqData['image'][0]['url'] = $faqData->getImageUrl();
        }
        $this->loadedData[$faq->getId()] = $faqData;
    }
    return $this->loadedData;
}
```

Comment: yes this was the solution i was looking for. Works great

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot to you all :)

Comment: @Raphael: I am facing an issue in image upload, I have posted a complete question here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257538/magento2-category-thumbnail-image-not-uploading. Can you please have a look into.

Comment: @Qaisar: I am facing an issue in image upload, I have posted a complete question here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257538/magento2-category-thumbnail-image-not-uploading. Can you please have a look into.

Answer (score 5):

You can fine out complete working code from below. Kindly check it from your side.

> app/code/vendor/modulename/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register
(\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,'Vendor_modulename',__DIR__);
```

> app/code/vendor/modulename/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="vendor_modulename" setup_version="1.0.3" active="true">
    </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/vendor/modulename/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="faqs" frontName="faqs">
            <module name="vendor_modulename" before="Magento_Backend" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> app/code/vendor/modulename/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader" type="vendor\modulename\Model\ImageUploader" />
    <type name="vendor\modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Topic\Image\Upload">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUploadFaqs</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUploadFaqs" type="vendor\modulename\Model\ImageUploader">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">catalog/tmp/category</argument>
            <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">catalog/category</argument>
            <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
                <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
                <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
                <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

> app/code/vendor/modulename/Controller/Adminhtml/Topic/Image/Upload.php

```
<?php
namespace vendor\modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Topic\Image;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * Image uploader
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader
     */
    protected $baseTmpPath;
    protected $imageUploader;

    /**
     * Upload constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \vendor\modulename\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
    }

    /**
     * Check admin permissions for this controller
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('vendor_modulename::entity');
    }

    /**
     * Upload file controller action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {

        try {
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('image');

            $result['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
    }
}
```

> app/code/vendor/modulename/Model/ImageUploader.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace vendor\modulename\Model;
//echo "sdfsdf";exit;
/**
 * Catalog image uploader
 */
class ImageUploader 
{
    /**
     * Core file storage database
     *
     * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database
     */
    protected $coreFileStorageDatabase;

    /**
     * Media directory object (writable).
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface
     */
    protected $mediaDirectory;

    /**
     * Uploader factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory
     */
    private $uploaderFactory;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * Base tmp path
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $baseTmpPath;

    /**
     * Base path
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $basePath;

    /**
     * Allowed extensions
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $allowedExtensions;

    /**
     * ImageUploader constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDatabase
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param string $baseTmpPath
     * @param string $basePath
     * @param string[] $allowedExtensions
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDatabase,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        $baseTmpPath,
        $basePath,
        $allowedExtensions
    ) {
        $this->coreFileStorageDatabase = $coreFileStorageDatabase;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->baseTmpPath = $baseTmpPath;
        $this->basePath = $basePath;
        $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;
    }

    /**
     * Set base tmp path
     *
     * @param string $baseTmpPath
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setBaseTmpPath($baseTmpPath)
    {
        $this->baseTmpPath = $baseTmpPath;
    }

    /**
     * Set base path
     *
     * @param string $basePath
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setBasePath($basePath)
    {
        $this->basePath = $basePath;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowed extensions
     *
     * @param string[] $allowedExtensions
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAllowedExtensions($allowedExtensions)
    {
        $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve base tmp path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBaseTmpPath()
    {

        return $this->baseTmpPath;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve base path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBasePath()
    {
        return $this->basePath;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve base path
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getAllowedExtensions()
    {
        return $this->allowedExtensions;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve path
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param string $imageName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFilePath($path, $imageName)
    {
        return rtrim($path, '/') . '/' . ltrim($imageName, '/');
    }

    /**
     * Checking file for moving and move it
     *
     * @param string $imageName
     *
     * @return string
     *
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function moveFileFromTmp($imageName)
    {
        $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();
        $basePath = $this->getBasePath();


        $baseImagePath = $this->getFilePath($basePath, $imageName);
        $baseTmpImagePath = $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $imageName);

        try {
            $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->copyFile(
                $baseTmpImagePath,
                $baseImagePath
            );
            $this->mediaDirectory->renameFile(
                $baseTmpImagePath,
                $baseImagePath
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('Something went wrong while saving the file(s).')
            );
        }

        return $imageName;
    }

    /**
     * Checking file for save and save it to tmp dir
     *
     * @param string $fileId
     *
     * @return string[]
     *
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function saveFileToTmpDir($fileId)
    {
        $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();

        $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $fileId]);
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions($this->getAllowedExtensions());
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);

        $result = $uploader->save($this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($baseTmpPath));

        if (!$result) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('File can not be saved to the destination folder.')
            );
        }

        /**
         * Workaround for prototype 1.7 methods "isJSON", "evalJSON" on Windows OS
         */
        $result['tmp_name'] = str_replace('\\', '/', $result['tmp_name']);
        $result['path'] = str_replace('\\', '/', $result['path']);
        $result['url'] = $this->storeManager
                ->getStore()
                ->getBaseUrl(
                    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
                ) . $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $result['file']);
        $result['name'] = $result['file'];

        if (isset($result['file'])) {
            try {
                $relativePath = rtrim($baseTmpPath, '/') . '/' . ltrim($result['file'], '/');
                $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->saveFile($relativePath);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e);
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __('Something went wrong while saving the file(s).')
                );
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any query/concern from above.

Comment: still same issue.

Comment: add more code which you have used for it.

Comment: can you add complete module code ?

Comment: You are use code for new category image attribute ?

Comment: i have now added all code for image uploader that i have used in module

Comment: @S H Patel yes i am modifying new category image upload code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47856/discussion-between-s-h-patel-and-ashar-riaz).

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: When you complete your change, remove /var/* folder and check your chages.

Comment: Have you try complete this code ?

Comment: i have accepted above answer the issue was in data provider which is resolved after converting array to acceptable format

Comment: My code is not working from your side ?

Comment: hi thanks for your help actually the issue was that for image we have to return image array in proper format which contains image name and image url. by default it is just string of image name so  Qaisar and  Raphael gives the solution for that

Comment: @SureshChikani, can we use this product attachments? will this support bulk attachments