# Magento 2: Implement UI Fileuploader

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent, file-upload, magento2.2

I recently implemented the [FileUploader Ui Component](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-fileuploader.html) in my form on Magento 2.1.7.

The code for it is here (**app/code/Vendor/Blog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/vendor_blog_form.xml**):

```
<field name="featured_images">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Hervorgehobene Bilder:</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="string">jpg jpeg gif png</item>
                    <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Erlaubte Dateitypen: png, gif, jpg, jpeg.</item>
                    <item name="maxFileSize" xsi:type="number">2097152</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">blog</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">featured_images</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="vendor_blog/blog/upload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

My Controller for it is this (**app/code/Vendor/Blog/Controller/Adminhtml/Blog/Upload.php**):

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Blog\Controller\Adminhtml\Blog;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;  

class Upload extends \Vendor\Blog\Controller\Adminhtml\Blog
{

    protected $_fileUploaderFactory;
    protected $_directory_list;
    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directory_list,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
        $this->_directory_list = $directory_list;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context, $coreRegistry);
    }

    public function execute(){
        $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'featured_images']);
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
        $path = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('blog');
        //$path = $this->_directory_list->getPath('media') . '/blog';
        $this->_logger->debug('Uploader.php: '.$path);
        $uploader->save($path);
    }
}
```

However, when I upload an image and inspect the call in Chrome's console, I get an Error 500 with Exception: **$_FILES array is empty**.

I am struggling for two days but I can't get it to work right. When I uncomment the alternate `$path` variable line, the Upload succeeds but I do not get a preview.

I read that it might be the `enctype` of the form that's causing the issue, but I didn't find any information on how to check this for a UI Component form.

If you need the whole exception code please let me know.

I appreciate every help possible. Thank you!

Comment: why dont yo try another way of upload?
for eg. 
https://webkul.com/blog/upload-an-image-from-customer-edit-form-magento-2-0/

Comment: Sadly I am limited to only use the pure UI Components with XML declaration for this extension. But it would be a nice alternative though.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I follow this steps to add UI fileuploader component in admin form

I use UI fileuploader component to upload an icon for my FAQ extension. You can take reference from here: https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-FAQ

**1) Add field in `admin_form.xml`(Admin Form)**

```
<field name="icon">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">FaqGroup</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Group Image</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
            <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/image-preview</item>
            <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
            <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="your_router/faqgroup/upload"/>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

**2) Now we need to create controller which we define in `uploaderConfig` in admin form: `<item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="vendor_module/faqgroup/upload"/>`**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/FaqGroup/Upload.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\FaqGroup;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public $imageUploader;
   
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
    }
    
    public function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Vendor_Module::Faq');
    }
   
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('icon');
            $result['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
    }
}
```

**3) Create `ImageUploader.php`**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ImageUploader.php

```
<?php

namespace Prince\Faq\Model;

class ImageUploader
{
    private $coreFileStorageDatabase;
    private $mediaDirectory;
    private $uploaderFactory;
    private $storeManager;
    private $logger;
    public $baseTmpPath;
    public $basePath;
    public $allowedExtensions;
 
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDatabase,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->coreFileStorageDatabase = $coreFileStorageDatabase;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->baseTmpPath = "faq/tmp/icon";
        $this->basePath = "faq/icon";
        $this->allowedExtensions= ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'];
    }
    
    public function setBaseTmpPath($baseTmpPath)
    {
        $this->baseTmpPath = $baseTmpPath;
    }
    
    public function setBasePath($basePath)
    {
        $this->basePath = $basePath;
    }
    
    public function setAllowedExtensions($allowedExtensions)
    {
        $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;
    }
   
    public function getBaseTmpPath()
    {
        return $this->baseTmpPath;
    }
   
    public function getBasePath()
    {
        return $this->basePath;
    }
   
    public function getAllowedExtensions()
    {
        return $this->allowedExtensions;
    }
   
    public function getFilePath($path, $imageName)
    {
        return rtrim($path, '/') . '/' . ltrim($imageName, '/');
    }
   
    public function moveFileFromTmp($imageName)
    {
        $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();
        $basePath = $this->getBasePath();
        $baseImagePath = $this->getFilePath($basePath, $imageName);
        $baseTmpImagePath = $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $imageName);
        try {
            $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->copyFile(
                $baseTmpImagePath,
                $baseImagePath
            );
            $this->mediaDirectory->renameFile(
                $baseTmpImagePath,
                $baseImagePath
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('Something went wrong while saving the file(s).')
            );
        }
        return $imageName;
    }
  
    public function saveFileToTmpDir($fileId)
    {
        $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();
        $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $fileId]);
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions($this->getAllowedExtensions());
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $result = $uploader->save($this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($baseTmpPath));
        if (!$result) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('File can not be saved to the destination folder.')
            );
        }
        
        $result['tmp_name'] = str_replace('\\', '/', $result['tmp_name']);
        $result['path'] = str_replace('\\', '/', $result['path']);
        $result['url'] = $this->storeManager
                ->getStore()
                ->getBaseUrl(
                    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
                ) . $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $result['file']);
        $result['name'] = $result['file'];
        if (isset($result['file'])) {
            try {
                $relativePath = rtrim($baseTmpPath, '/') . '/' . ltrim($result['file'], '/');
                $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->saveFile($relativePath);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e);
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __('Something went wrong while saving the file(s).')
                );
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**4) Create `image-preview.html`**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/template/image-preview.html

```
<div class="file-uploader-summary">
    <div class="file-uploader-preview">
        <a attr="href: $parent.getFilePreview($file)" target="_blank">
            <img
                class="preview-image"
                tabindex="0"
                event="load: $parent.onPreviewLoad.bind($parent)"
                attr="
                    src: $parent.getFilePreview($file),
                    alt: $file.name">
        </a>

        <div class="actions">
            <button
                type="button"
                class="action-remove"
                data-role="delete-button"
                attr="title: $t('Delete image')"
                click="$parent.removeFile.bind($parent, $file)">
                <span translate="'Delete image'"/>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="file-uploader-filename" text="$file.name"/>
    <div class="file-uploader-meta">
        <text args="$file.previewWidth"/>x<text args="$file.previewHeight"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**5) Now add arguments for `ImageUploader.php` in di.xml**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Model\ImageUploader">
        <arguments>
            <!-- Temporary file stored in pub/media/faq/tmp/icon -->
            <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">faq/tmp/icon</argument>
            <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">faq/icon</argument>
            <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
                <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
                <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
                <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Check this file for load uploaded image on edit form: [DataProvider.php](https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-FAQ/blob/master/Prince/Faq/Model/FaqGroup/DataProvider.php)

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**To save image in database**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Save.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $dataPersistor;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
    ) {
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        ...
        ...
        $data = $this->_filterFoodData($data);
        $model->setData($data);
        $model->save();
        ...
        ...     
    }

    public function _filterFoodData(array $rawData)
    {
        //Replace icon with fileuploader field name
        $data = $rawData;
        if (isset($data['icon'][0]['name'])) {
            $data['icon'] = $data['icon'][0]['name'];
        } else {
            $data['icon'] = null;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

**To show uploaded image in form edit page:**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/DataProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    ...
    ...

    public function getData()
    {
        ...
        ...
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        
        //Replace icon with fileuploader field name
        foreach ($items as $model) {
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $model->getData();
            if ($model->getIcon()) {
                $m['icon'][0]['name'] = $model->getIcon();
                $m['icon'][0]['url'] = $this->getMediaUrl().$model->getIcon();
                $fullData = $this->loadedData;
                $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = array_merge($fullData[$model->getId()], $m);
            }
        }
        ...
        ...
        
        return $this->loadedData;
    }

    public function getMediaUrl()
    {
        $mediaUrl = $this->storeManager->getStore()
            ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'faq/tmp/icon/';
        return $mediaUrl;
    }
}
```

**Edited** Date:- 2nd August, 2021

**If you got Error like "Uncaught TypeError: value.map is not a function at UiClass.setInitialValue (file-uploader.js:80)"**

Or You can't see Value in Inputs field at edit page

then first of all check your Array which is Returns from DataProviders...

for Show Image at edit Page you need to return array in below sample format.
[image: Array which is return from DataProviders]

I was returned wrong array using Above DataProvider Source. So I have done some changes in **public function getData()** function and Its works for me... see below changes

```
public function getData()
{
    ...
    ...
    $items = $this->collection->getItems();

    //Replace icon with fileuploader field name
    foreach ($items as $model) {
        $this->loadedData[$model->getId()]['post'] = $model->getData(); 
        //Note that: I used ['post] in above line because I was already defined  *<fieldset name="post">* at Form UI Component's xml File... you have to use as your respective... even you can see above Screenshot of Array I return Data in Post Array Object, that why I use ['post']

        if ($model->getIcon()) {
            $m[0]['name'] = $model->getIcon();
            $m[0]['url'] = $this->getMediaUrl().$model->getIcon();
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()]['post']['featured_image'] = $m;
        }
    }
    ...
    ...

    return $this->loadedData;
}
```

you can Debug your Array at DataProvider like this

```
echo '<script> console.log('. json_encode($this->loadedData) .') </script>';
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, really appreciate it. However when I implement your solution and upload an Image, my returned response in Chrome's console is: {"error":"$_FILES array is empty","errorcode":0}. The file has not been uploaded (I checked chmod) and of course the preview cannot show up.

Comment: Actually I got it working finally with the help of your code. So thank you very much! You are my hero! :-)

Comment: You're most welcome :)

Comment: @PrincePatel this is just great, but assuming i have an edit form, how can I make the image-preview template read from the getData from the data provider

Comment: @PrincePatel found answer to that here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138642/magento-2-1-image-not-uploading-in-edit-form

Comment: @YehiaA.Salam check this file: https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-FAQ/blob/master/Prince/Faq/Model/FaqGroup/DataProvider.php

Comment: can I add this as  attribute for product in catalog ?

Comment: It is working for a single image field, But if I have multiple image fields  which is need to upload a image and also need to show preview for each images. Can you provide me a solution

Comment: @sri Refer this module I use two file uploader field in ui form: https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-productlabel

Comment: @PrincePatel In above code Inside Imageuploader.php, In constructor You have set the extensions, But my scenario, I have set allowed extensions in system configuration, I got the system config values in helper file, Now How do I set my system config value in constructor itself

Comment: In constructor , I had set like    $this->allowedExtensions = $this->helper->getImageFileTypes();  but it shows an 500 error

Comment: @sri This issue is not related to this question. Please ask other question about this issue to make clean communication.

Comment: @PrincePatel, thank you for the response, I have solved the issue

Comment: Now I have posted my issue by refering your code. Please have a glance https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/211831/admingrid-ui-component-form-in-magento-2

Comment: As far as I can tell, this code saves to a temporary directory, and doesn't ever move it from there.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Can we display the loading icon when when the file is being uploaded ?

Comment: hi @PrincePatel , can use it for file csv ?

Comment: @PrincePatel I'm working in Magento 2.3 and calling "ImageUploader" from di.xml and sending baseTmpPath, basePath and allowedExtensions params from the same. Now my model "ImageUploader" throws an error "Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $baseTmpPath". Can you please help me how to manage from di.xml instead of statically set in "ImageUploader" model's constructor function?

Comment: I got {"error":"The file was not uploaded.","errorcode":666} any idea about this error

Comment: @PrincePatel, how to use it for product file attachment? do we need to create any attribute, can you please suggest on it

Comment: Worth noting that in order to display the image after saving within the admin (the edit view) or to be able to show the image on the frontend via something like $model->getIcon() you need to add the image column to your database via InstallSchema or UpgradeSchema.

Answer (score 6):

### Supplement for Magento 2.2 UI component

Compare with Magento 2.1, in **Magento 2.2**, the **UI component** had some **optional differences** like below. We could make use of the official `Magento_Catalog/image-preview` as preview templete, and the rest of codes like controller could refer to the **accepted answer**.

```
<field name="image" formElement="fileUploader">
    <settings>
        <notice translate="true">Allowed file types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png.</notice>
        <label translate="true">Image</label>
        <componentType>fileUploader</componentType>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <fileUploader>
            <settings>
                <allowedExtensions>jpg jpeg gif png</allowedExtensions>
                <maxFileSize>10240000</maxFileSize>
                <placeholderType>image</placeholderType>
                <previewTmpl>Magento_Catalog/image-preview</previewTmpl>
                <uploaderConfig>
                    <param xsi:type="string" name="url">path/to/controller</param>
                </uploaderConfig>
            </settings>
        </fileUploader>
    </formElements>
</field>
```

Comment: I get the error `TypeError: value.map is not a function`. How can I fix it

Comment: @NeroPhung Hi, please try this solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/138642/44237

Comment: I have done this issue by myself within following that post. Thanks for the support!

Comment: @KeyShang , In your code , How and where  Do I put validation for image uploder field

Comment: @Sri I see your question, I will answer it in your question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/211957/ui-component-form-validation-for-file-uploader-field , give me some time.

Comment: @Sri I had a lunch just now and you delete your question, the maxFileSize and  allowedExtensions you could see my answer, other validation you could see the top answer and put the validation codes in the upload controller `execute` method.

Comment: Thank you soo much @KeyShang. I have solved my issue after added the below code <validation>
                            <rule xsi:type="boolean" active="false" name="required-entry">true</rule>
                        </validation>