# Magento2 : How to Image upload and display form in custom admin module

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin, uicomponent

I am trying to upload an Image and display a form in a custom admin-module using UI components

```
   <field name="events_url">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">event</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Scale_Events/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="events/test/upload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

Controller

```
<?php
namespace Scale\Events\Controller\Adminhtml\Test;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    protected $_fileUploaderFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
        Action\Context $context
    ) {
        $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute(){
        $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'image']);
        var_dump($uploader); die();
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
        $path = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)
            ->getAbsolutePath('images/');

        echo $path; die();
        $uploader->save($path);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Check this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/186781/35758

Comment: @Prince Patel Getting  error  Attention

The file was not uploaded.