# Upload image equal media gallery Magento 2

Tags: magento2, image-upload

[image]

```
        $fieldset->addField('media_gallery', 'note',
        [
            'label' => '',
            'title' => __('Media Gallery'),
            'name'  => 'media_gallery',
            // 'required' => true,
            'text'      => $this->getContentHtml(),
        ]
    );

    $fieldset->addField('media_gallery_mobile', 'note',
        [
            'label' => '',
            'title' => __('Media Gallery For Mobile'),
            'name'  => 'media_gallery_mobile',
            // 'required' => true,
            'text'      => $this->getContentHtml(),
        ]
    );
```

I have two fields like this in form, how can I save 2 different photos, hope anyone help me. Thank you.

Comment: This all depends on how the extension has been built, as if it was specifically made for a single image then the upload functionality may be coded to only use the media_gallery variable if that is the case you would either need to change it to allow any variable that is posted or create new upload functionality that will allow you to upload a mobile image

Comment: can you give me an example? Thank you.

Comment: Rather than reinvent the wheel please look at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184731/magento-2-implement-ui-fileuploader for reference