# How to set UiComponent imageUploader Width and Height in Magento 2.3.4?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, image-upload

I'm using Magento 2.3.4, and now I'm extending the category form to add new field input image like this:

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml**

```
  <field name="banner_io" sortOrder="40" formElement="imageUploader">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/uploader/image</elementTmpl>
            <dataType>string</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Banner IO</label>
            <comment translate="true">Dimension: 900px X 354px</comment>
            <visible>true</visible>
            <required>false</required>
            <scopeLabel>[STORE VIEW]</scopeLabel>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <imageUploader>
                <settings>
                    <required>false</required>
                    <uploaderConfig>
                        <param xsi:type="url" name="url" path="catalog/category_image/upload"/>
                    </uploaderConfig>
                    <previewTmpl>Magento_Catalog/image-preview</previewTmpl>
                    <openDialogTitle>Media Gallery</openDialogTitle>
                    <initialMediaGalleryOpenSubpath>catalog/category</initialMediaGalleryOpenSubpath>
                    <allowedExtensions>jpg jpeg gif png</allowedExtensions>
                    <maxFileSize>4194304</maxFileSize>
                </settings>
            </imageUploader>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

in here I can set the max file size, how I can set minimum/maximum width and height?

Comment: you can try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184731/magento-2-implement-ui-fileuploader

Comment: You must add custom code to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can set Width & Height in dashboard.

```
Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System > Images Upload Configuration
```

[image]

Comment: Is this gonna effect all the image uploader ? i just need it for this specific input not all