# Custom Import a csv file Action in Admin Grid Form page?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, uicomponent

I am trying to retrive the upload file on form submit in admin grid.

In that I did not get the filepath because of the $model->getdata not able to find the path on line 123 in below code.

```
 <?php
        /**
        * Webkul_Grid Add New Row Form Admin Block.
        * @category    Webkul
        * @package     Webkul_Grid
        * @author      Webkul Software Private Limited
        *
        */
        namespace Webkul\Grid\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Edit;

        /**
        * Adminhtml Add New Row Form.
        */
        class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
        {
        /**
        * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
        */
        protected $_systemStore;

        /**
        * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig,
        * @param \Webkul\Grid\Model\Status $options,
        */
        public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig,
        \Webkul\Grid\Model\Status $options,
        array $data = []
        ) {
        $this->_options = $options;
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
        }

        /**
        * Prepare form.
        *
        * @return $this
        */
        protected function _prepareForm()
        {
        $dateFormat = $this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('row_data');
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
        ['data' => [
        'id' => 'edit_form',
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
        'action' => $this->getData('action'),
        'method' => 'post'
        ]
        ]
        );

        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('shipment_');

        $fieldset->addField(
        'content',
        'editor',
        [
        'name' => 'content',
        'label' => __('Content'),
        'style' => 'height:36em;',
        'required' => true,
        'config' => $wysiwygConfig
        ]
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
        'publish_date',
        'date',
        [
        'name' => 'publish_date',
        'label' => __('Publish Date'),
        'date_format' => $dateFormat,
        'time_format' => 'H:mm:ss',
        'class' => 'validate-date validate-date-range date-range-custom_theme-from',
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'style' => 'width:200px',
        ]
        );
        $importdata_script =  $fieldset->addField(
        'importdata',
        'file',
        array(
        'label'     => 'Upload File',
        'required'  => true,
        'name'      => 'importdata',
        'note' => 'Allow File type: .csv and .xls',
        )
        );


        $importdata_script =  $fieldset->setAfterElementHtml(
        "   


        <script type=\"text/javascript\">

        document.getElementById('grid_importdata').onchange = function () { 

        var fileInput = document.getElementById('grid_importdata');

        var filePath = fileInput.value;

        var allowedExtensions = /(\.csv|\.xls)$/i; 

        if(!allowedExtensions.exec(filePath))
        {
        alert('Please upload file having extensions .csv or .xls only.');
        fileInput.value = '';
        }

        };

        </script>"
        );
        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
        }
        }
```

Comment: Why not use the UI Form ?

Comment: In UI form how we retrive the data from import file.

Comment: on controlloer action.

Comment: There will be 2 controllers:
1. Upload: on upload of a file, this will save the  in tmp and return the URL to UI Form

2. Save: on form save, this will receive the tmp file path which you can read and process values.

Comment: on form save, could you provide an example.
asabove seen I am facing the issue to render the data on save action.

Comment: follow this URL --> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184731/magento-2-implement-ui-fileuploader