# Custom file upload in ui-component form

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, adminform, file-upload

I am trying to get file upload working in a ui-component admin form. The file input field is coming from a `htmlContent` block. This is all sitting in a `<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">` element.

Now the issue is that the form element is not actually being rendered as html, as such I cannot add/apply `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to this form and `$_FILES` remains empty upon submitting.

Attempts to change the uiComponent to include form element and/or enctype definition failed as it doesn't allow usage of such elements/attributes in the ui-component file directly (`collapsible.xhtml`). How to move forward with this?

Code example:

Form definition

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        [...]
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="enctype" xsi:type="string">multipart/form-data</item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        [...]
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="XXX">
        [...]
    </dataSource>
    [...]
    <fieldset name="XXX" sortOrder="20">
        <settings>
            <collapsible>false</collapsible>
            <opened>true</opened>
            <label translate="true">Products</label>
        </settings>
        <htmlContent name="custom_field">
            <block name="html_content_input_field" class="XXXX">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">
                        XXX.phtml
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </htmlContent>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

XXX.phtml - Simplified as the file is nested in an array-like structure set up with Knockout

```
<div>
    <input type="file" name="nameforfile" data-form-part="the-correct-name"/>
</div>
```

All textual data is send - even the fake file name of the file but not the file itself. I don't need instant upload and/or visible files - Solely the data of the file actually being send to the server.

Raw POST data looks like:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryvmSygS0ldVua30Aw
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="author_id"

1
[...] etc
```

Comment: just follow basic Magento code standard for file upload.
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/ui-components/components/file-uploader/

Comment: It should come from a html file, not a ui-component as it's nested in a htmlContent

Comment: Can you please share your code so that we can better understand the problem?

Comment: @msquare Edited/added minimum code example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If you need a file uploader in a UI component, you can use their default component, which provides a way to upload a file with data and save it in your controller. When you create a form using UI component, it does not create form elements; that's why you cannot get file data into the controller. If you want file data, your input must be inside a form tag, and the enctype attribute value must be multipart/form-data, which is not available in a UI component.*

*To implement a file uploader with UI components, consider using a combination of UI components and a traditional form for handling file uploads. This way, you can achieve the desired functionality while still working within the constraints of UI components.*

File Upload into UI component: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/186781/82670

**And if you don't have an option for it, you need to add an AJAX call, as described in the above answer link. In UI components, a similar approach is used—when you upload anything, it triggers an AJAX controller that stores the file in a temporary location. You can follow a similar approach here. Below is a small example of how to retrieve file data in a UI form**

**Form UI Component**

```
<fieldset name="test_uploader">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Test Image Uploader</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <container name="test_uploader_container" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <htmlContent name="html_content">
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\CustomData</argument>
        </htmlContent>
    </container>
</fieldset>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml**

**CustomData.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository;

class CustomData extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{
    protected $_systemStore;

    protected $_countryFactory;

    protected $_assetRepo;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country $countryFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
        $this->_assetRepo = $assetRepo;
        $this->_countryFactory = $countryFactory;
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        // $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('row_data');

        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            ['data' => [
                            'id' => 'custom_form',
                            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                            'action' => $this->getData('action'),
                            'method' => 'post',
                            'data-form-part' => "custom_form",
                        ]
            ]
        );

        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('storelocation_');

           $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
                'base_fieldset',
                ['legend' => __('General Information'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
            );

       $importdata_script =  $fieldset->addField(
            'importdata',
            'file',
                array(
                        'label'     => 'Upload File',
                        'name'      => 'importdata',
                        'data-form-part' => "custom_form",
                     )
        );

        $importdata_script->setAfterElementHtml("

        <span id='sample-file-span' >

            <script type=\"text/javascript\">

            document.getElementById('storelocation_importdata').onchange = function () {

                var fileInputData =  document.getElementById('storelocation_importdata').files[0];
                console.log(fileInputData);

            };

            </script>"
        );


        // $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

**You can display file data in the console when selected using file input and implement AJAX to save it to a temporary path, similar to what the UI component does for file uploading.**

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your complete response. Sorry I'm not working this fulltime, thus responding slow. So it is a hard constraint in UI-Components. Bad design imo, but okay. It's sad as the images should be attached to an array-like entity which may not exist in DB yet, why I tried so hard to have it in one POST. Many thanks again!