# How to add custom Image attribute to category in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, category, overrides, custom-field

Can you help me to add custom field for the image on my category?

I want to add a thumbnail for my category via admin panel, and then get it on front-end.

I have now eav attribute in `eav_attribute` table, but it still doesn't appear in admin panel.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116214/adding-an-image-form-element-to-an-add-edit-form

Comment: @HoangHieu , no that is how to make admin field for custom module. But I want to add thumbnail to category (existing magento module)

Comment: You can get help from : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138928/add-new-image-attribute-for-category-in-magento-2-1-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    protected $categorySetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory    
        ....
    ) {
        ....
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;    
        ....
    }
```

Now In your setup file you can use this like,

```
         $setup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);         
         $setup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'custom_image', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Custom Image',
                'input' => 'image',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 9,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'General Information',
            ]
        );
```

Comment: It works and eav attribute added to table, but there is no field in admin panel to add image

Comment: Yes, it was my bad sorry :) , I think its too long answer but you can use this blog https://belvg.com/blog/how-to-add-image-attribute-to-a-category-in-magento-2.html

Comment: Thanks! It works, but when I try to save, it returns me 404 error from my ajax in my browser console

Comment: Glad to hear that, in that case you can ask a new question with your code so someone can answer your question @KyryloRomantsov

Comment: check out my new question please https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192801/issues-with-adding-image-attribute-to-category-magento-2